# Plotly X-Axis Margin

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, plotly

Attach is a graph I produced using Plotly. I was able to make many cosmetic changes to it, however, The last step is for me to decrease the margin between "Experiment ID" and the Xaxis line. I have researched but wasn't able to find the answer. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank You.
[image]

Answer (score 3):

Based on your graph. You need to play around with the margins of the page. Please check the below layout and apply it to your page!

```
layout = {
    'margin': {
        'l':0,
        'r':0,
        't':0,
        'b':0
    }
}
```

To know more about margins, visit [The official reference docs](https://plot.ly/python/reference/#layout-margin).

Please let me know if the suggestion solved your issue!

Comment: @ArenMarkBoghozian Did this help you?

Answer (score 0):

I found the option `title_standoff` for that in Plotly go objects. It works with both axes.

I give you an example:

```py
import plotly.graph_objs as go

fig = go.Figure()

fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=[1, 2, 3], y=[4, 5, 6]))

fig.update_layout(
    yaxis=dict(
        title="Y-axis Title",
        titlefont=dict(size=16),
        tickfont=dict(size=14),
        title_standoff=10 # The higher the value, the farther away it is displayed
    ),
    xaxis = dict(
        title="X-axis Title",
        titlefont=dict(size=16),
        tickfont=dict(size=14),
        title_standoff=50 # The higher the value, the farther away it is displayed
    ),
)

fig.show()
```

This is the result:

[image: plot_results_xaxis_margin]